# Referencing functions enclosing table in Lua

Tags: lua, closures

I have a helper function which returns a table like this:

```
function of_type(expected_type)
    return {
        expected = expected_type,
        matches = function(value) return type(value) == expected_type end,
        describe = "type " .. expected_type
    }
end
```

Now this was fine with other matchers but here I would like to store the `type(value)` to a field in the same table when the `matches` function is called. Something like this:

```
function of_type(expected_type)
    return {
        expected = expected_type,
        mismatch = nil, -- set it to nil on initialization
        matches = function(value) 
            mismatch = type(value)  -- how to do this?
            return type(value) == expected_type
        end,
        describe = "type " .. expected_type
    }
end
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I do not recommend doing this.  It is counterintuitive for a "passive" method like `matches` to change the state of the object.  Consider returning multiple values instead, e.g. `return false, mismatch` if the types don't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you need to split it into steps:

```
function of_type(expected_type)
    local tbl = {
        expected = expected_type,
        mismatch = nil, -- set it to nil on initialization
        describe = "type " .. expected_type
    }
    tbl.matches = function(value) 
        tbl.mismatch = type(value)
        return type(value) == tbl.expected
    end
    return tbl
end

-- testing it
local foo = of_type("string")
print(foo.matches(1), foo.matches("1"))
```

This should output `false true` as you would expect.

Essentially, `tbl.matches` will store the reference to `tbl` (it's called "upvalue") and will be able to modify all the fields in that table (including the reference to itself it in).

**Another way** to do this would be the following (notice the changes in the tbl.matches function). Instead of capturing it as an upvalue, you can use `tbl:method` semantic and pass `tbl` as implicit `self` parameter:

```
    function of_type(expected_type)
        local tbl = {
            expected = expected_type,
            mismatch = nil, -- set it to nil on initialization
            describe = "type " .. expected_type
        }
        function tbl:matches(value) 
                self.mismatch = type(value)  -- how to do this?
                return type(value) == self.expected
            end
        return tbl
    end

local foo = of_type("string")
print(foo:matches(1), foo:matches("1"))
```

This will print the same result. Notice that you are using `foo:matches` notation to make `foo` to be passed as the first parameter (references as `self` in the method). This is the same as using `foo.matches(foo, 1)`.

Comment: I'm marking this as accepted because you did thoroughly answer my question. However I will go by the suggestion of @finnw and instead return both the boolean and the mismatch description from the function so there's no unnecessary state information left dangling in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Well, not without storing a copy of the table, or passing the function the table as a parameter. Until all of the statements of the table constructor have been processed, the table doesn't exist yet. And since you never stored it anywhere (in this function), your function can't name it in order to find it.

So you should give it a name, even just for a moment:

```
function of_type(expected_type)
  local temp = nil
  temp = {
        expected = expected_type,
        mismatch = nil, -- set it to nil on initialization
        matches = function(value) 
            temp.mismatch = type(value)  -- Like this
            return type(value) == expected_type
        end,
        describe = "type " .. expected_type
    }
  return temp
end
```

This works because Lua will store `temp` as an upvalue. Thus, the function you're creating will see changes in `temp`, such as when you set it to a table value. And since it's a local variable, it won't be visible outside of this function.